# Link to Jenkins Build with UI interface

Tags: java, angularjs, jenkins

I want to display all build of Jenkins in my UI.

Is there any way to pull all the build history and display on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Jenkins xml api to get this information:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/job/test_job/api/xml");
// read information into DOM.
Document dom = new SAXReader().read(url);
// scan through build list of test_job job and print its info
for (Element build : (List<Element>) dom.getRootElement().elements("build")) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Number:%s\tUrl:%s", build.elementText("number"), build.elementText("url")));
}
```

Have a look at this example:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/extras-client-demo